# Sub-indexing a list to apply a function in R

Tags: r

I have a list of 4 data frames in R, such that each element of the list contains data ordered by atom number(factor) e.g.

```
$P1
AtomNum  Moiety  Energy
1519     P1      -1.2
1519     P1      -1.6
1520     P1      -2.3
1520     P1      -2.4
1521     P1      -3.6
1521     P1      -3.1 

$P1' 
AtonNum   Moiety   Energy
1522      P1'      -3.5
1522      P1'      -3.1    
1523      P1'      -2.5
1523      P1'      -2.9
1524      P1'      -1.8
1524      P1'      -1.5

$P2 
AtomNum   Moiety    Energy
1525      P2        -1.1
1525      P2        -1.9
1526      P2        -1.8 
1526      P2        -1.7
1527      P2        -3.1
1527      P2        -2.9

$P2'
AtomNum   Moiety    Energy
1528       P2'      -3.4 
1528       P2'      -3.6 
1529       P2'      -2.7 
1529       P2'      -2.5 
1530       P2'      -1.7 
1530       P2'      -1.2
```

I don't know if this is possible, but I would like to take the mean of the energy values per atom (group) and then sum these values for each element of the list. Something to the effect of

> sum(mean(x$AtomNum)) where x is the list

Can I do this with the data in a list form?

Comment: If you have identical columns, why are you keeping them in a list of 4 data frames instead of just a single data frame? You can combine them by `l <- do.call(rbind, l)` and then all the operations will be straightforward.

Comment: @DavidArenburg "...and then sum these values for each element of the list". I guess the split across several DFs must have some meaning.

Comment: @Frank I have no idea what's that mysterious "element of a list" means but you can easily add an `id` when combining either with base R or the devel version of `data.table::rbindlist`. It also seems like each list already have a unique identifier in the `Moiety` column.

Comment: Yeah, it seems the distinction across elements of the list is fully captured by the moiety column, so Cath's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for your input, they are in a list of 4 elements because I wan the output to be returned in a succinct manner by moiety.

Comment: Also I started with using an ordered data frame and then split the data frame by moiety hoping that I would get the answer I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Why did you split by `moiety`? Also, can you show us how the desired output should look like?

Comment: Hi David, I was trying to achieve the output that Frank has achieved from his updated comment. This is why I split by Moiety.

Comment: You don't need to split the data in order to perform aggregations. See `?aggregate`, `?tapply`. Also take a look at `dplyr` and `data.table` packages. No one splits the data anymore. That's old school.

Comment: ahahaha! Thanks David. I'm new to R I have these packages installed, but I'm still trying to learn my way around base R, so it's my first resort for the time being until I am more comfortable. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to have the mean of energy by `AtomNum` and `Moiety`, and then sum by `Moiety`, you can do, using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
l_dt <- rbindlist(ll)
l_dt[, mean(Energy), by=.(AtomNum, Moiety)][, .(Energy=sum(V1)), by=Moiety]
#   Moiety Energy
#1:     P1  -7.10
#2:     P2  -6.25
```

**data**

```
ll <- structure(list(P1 = structure(list(AtomNum = c(1519L, 1519L, 
1520L, 1520L, 1521L, 1521L), Moiety = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "P1", class = "factor"), Energy = c(-1.2, 
-1.6, -2.3, -2.4, -3.6, -3.1)), .Names = c("AtomNum", "Moiety", 
"Energy"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)), P2 = structure(list(
    AtomNum = c(1525L, 1525L, 1526L, 1526L, 1527L, 1527L), Moiety = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "P2", class = "factor"), Energy = c(-1.1, 
    -1.9, -1.8, -1.7, -3.1, -2.9)), .Names = c("AtomNum", "Moiety", 
"Energy"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))), .Names = c("P1", 
"P2"))
```

***EDIT***

In case you have a data.frame `df` and not a list, you can do:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[, mean(Energy), by=.(AtomNum, Moiety)][, .(Energy=sum(V1)), by=Moiety]
```

or, as mentioned by @DavidArenburg, using `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Moiety, AtomNum) %>% 
   summarise(Energy = mean(Energy)) %>% 
   summarise(sum(Energy))
```

Comment: great! :-) you're wlecome :-)  (if it solves your question, you can tick on the checkmark next to the answer so the question will leave the list of "not answered" ones)

Comment: one more thing, if one already has a data frame, can the final command be issued on its own?

Comment: in case you already have a data.frame, say `df`, you can do `setDT(df)[, mean(Energy), by=.(AtomNum, Moiety)][, .(Energy=sum(V1)), by=Moiety]` (`setDT` will change `df` to a data.table before doing the "operations"). I've edited the answer

Comment: yes! I was figuring it out while waiting for a response. Came to the same conclusion! Thanks again!

Comment: And ofcourse if you looking for additional 20 upvotes, you can add `library(dplyr) ; df %>% group_by(Moiety, AtomNum) %>% summarise(Energy = mean(Energy)) %>% summarise(sum(Energy))`

Answer (score 3):

Sure, use `sapply` to iterate over the list and `tapply` to iterate over groups:

```
sapply(ll, function(x) sum( with(x, tapply(Energy,AtomNum,mean)) ) )
```

Using @CathG's example data, this returns

```
   P1    P2 
-7.10 -6.25
```

I'd advocate binding the data.frames together instead, as covered in the other answer.

Comment: Hi, Thank you Frank. With this command, the returned list contains 4 NA values. Am I missing something?

Comment: @D.A.Ragland I can't really read your data in from what you've posted to check. I *think* something along these lines will work, but probably some tweak is required.

Comment: @D.A.Ragland Hm, it works for the data reported in Cath's answer.